# C Shell でsource hoge.env を実行したときにエラーが起こるはずが起きなかった

Tags: linux, csh

**hoge.csh**

```
#!/bin/csh -f
source hoge.env
[EOF]
```

**hoge.env**

```
# 本来はここで環境変数を設定している
set | grep -ai version  #バージョン表示
echhhho "おわり"[EOF]
```

**実行結果**

```
$ ./hoge.csh
version tcsh 6.17.00 (Astron) 2009-07-10 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,rh,color,filec
```

hoge.envで「echhhho」と綴りミスをしているため、「command not found」のエラーで終了するはずが、最後に改行をしていないことによって処理が行われていない（？）ため、正常終了。（気付かない）

別環境で実行をした時にエラーになったことで気付いた。

**実行結果**

```
$ ./hoge.csh
tcsh 6.18.01 (Astron) 2012-02-14 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec
echhhho: Command not found.
```

tcshのバージョンによる結果の違いなのでしょうか。（その場合ソースをお願いします！）
そう睨んでいたのですが、明記されているWEBページが見つからず、質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 2):

tcsh 6.17.03 での bug fix です。

https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/blob/48c44071d7c66ba4a7757376ff333d9e3bd820ba/Fixes#L227-L228

> 36. Error out when processing the last incomplete line instead of silently
>        ignoring it (Anders Kaseorg)